# Cohort Analysis on SaaS Users in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some SaaS users data, which looks as follows:

```
start_month end_month   User_Id
2019-10 2019-10 1
2019-10 2019-11 2
2019-10 2019-12 3
2019-10 2019-12 4
2019-11 2019-11 5
2019-11 2019-12 6
2019-11 2019-12 7
2019-11 2020-01 8
2019-12 2019-12 9
2019-12 2020-01 10
2019-12  NULL   11
2019-12 2020-02 12
```

As you can see, the data contains the subscription start date, and the subscription end date.

The start_month and end_month are strings created from start date as `TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month', start_date), 'yyyy-MM') AS start_month`

The `end_month` can be empty if the subscription is still active.

This is a postgresql database.

Using this data, I'm required to create a cohort report, which should show how many people started in each month, and from that cohort, how many ended the subscription in the subsequent month. In the above data, 4 users started in 2019-10. 1 ended in the same month (0), 1 ended in month 1, and 2 ended in month 2. Similarly, we should get for other start month cohorts.

I'm sorry, but I have absolutely no idea on how I can arrive at this report. I've searched the internet but couldn't find any relevant answers where cohort is created only with start and end dates. Please help.

Comment: First : use the correct datatypes (date), which makes comparisons easier. second: use +inf instead of NULL to indicate an everlasting interval. third: you need a calendar table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select start_month, count(*),
       count(*) filter (where end_month is null or to_date(end_month, 'YYYY-MM') >= to_date(start_month, 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1 month') as month_1,
       count(*) filter (where end_month is null or to_date(end_month, 'YYYY-MM') >= to_date(start_month, 'YYYY-MM') + interval '2 month') as month_2
from users u
group by start_month;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=41a3313af93fac5a035f73479adaa073) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: I will try this. But what I don't understand is that both the inner users table and the outer table as both alias 'u'. Is that okay?

Comment: @asanas . . . Yes that is okay, but there should be no inner query.

Comment: thanks so much for the effort. But the result is not as I was expecting. For example, for the users who joined in 2019-10, 1 left in same month_0 (2019-10), 1 left in month_1 (2019-11), and two left in month_2 (2019_12). The table should show this data of how many left in each subsequent month. Also is it possible to make it flexible to make it n months forward instead of just 2? Thanks once again.

Comment: @asanas . . . This should the ones who *did not leave*:  "how many ended the subscription in the subsequent month. "  You can add more months following similar logic.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, and thanks it works great. I am just trying to make the reverse work. That is, to show how many did leave in each month. Is that possible in this code?

Comment: @asana . . . Reverse the condition in the `where`.

Comment: Thanks. I did that but it doesn't show correctly. I also added a new month and that always shows all users. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1861cb7aad74011745df6198875710a2

Comment: @asanas . . . Use this:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7995b8e65e29711ab61cbd32de041e7b.  This answers the question that you asked here.  You should ask a *new* question if you have an additional question.